# openGL ES - drawing empty pixels

Tags: android, opengl-es, blending

I am in a situation where I need to render to a texture using FBO, and I need to remove some pixels from the buffer. That is, draw (0,0,0,0) color in a RGBA colored framebuffer. This will later allow me to later render this texture on top of another one and the 'zero pixels' will not be rendered since I use blending.

The problem is that I cannot draw such color on the screen because GL_BLEND is enabled while I am doing that and the zero pixels aren't rendered to the texture. 
So I have tried disabling GL_BLEND just before rendering to the texture, and 1. It continued blending like nothing happened, 2.At some point it renders of all the graphics without blending although it clearly receives the glEnable(GL_BLEND) call.

Here is most of the code:

```
gl.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CW);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glTranslatef(start_x+adv_x/2+adv_x*(float)col_idx, start_y+adv_y/2+adv_y*(float)j, -1.0f);
gl.glScalef(adv_x/2, adv_y/2, 1.0f);
gl.glColor4f(0,0,0,0);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertex.length / 3);
gl.glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
gl.glPopMatrix();
gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

This is code from an Android application, written in Java.
What can be the problem?

Comment: Why don't you skip blending and use the stencil buffer instead? This is exactly what it was created for. Modern hardware even has early stencil-test capabilities that can skip the expensive shading portion of rasterization (and later blending stage as well) when the stencil test would fail.

Comment: Another idea would be to move to OpenGL ES 2.0, where you have a lot more control over blending in the fragment shader.